# how do I convert column from different characters to 10 characters format in excel?

Tags: excel

I have a problem coding a column in excel with 10 characters instead of the original format "different characters number":

eg,

```
index     format_1          10_char_format
01        3081                3081000000      here there is no problem
02        102                 1020000000      
03        1020                1020000000
04        3081                3081000000      it can be repeated 
05        1020                1020000000      it can be repeated all can be repeated
```

in the second and the third the "format_1" is not the same bu it result in the the same "10_char_format".
Hhow I can solve his problem.

expected solution:

1. giving a correct method to code the "10_char_format".
2. identifying the wrong codification and correct them.

**more explanation :**

our new system is using a 10 char encoding instead of the old one we are trying to convert our old data, the error is ; as you see in the table the row 02 and 03 are different values "102" and "1020" but when we convert them to 10 char format they have the same value "1020000000", the result I want is to identify those error conversations and give them a unique code.

Comment: Could you please explain, a)the purpose of adding trailing Zeros and b)what seems to be the error/problem? and c)what result you are expecting in line 2 & 3?

Comment: our new system is using a 10 char encoding instead of the old one we are trying to convert our old data, the error is ; as you see in the table the row 02 and 03 are different values "102" and "1020" but when we convert them to 10 char format they have the same value "1020000000", the result I want is to identify those error conversations and give them a unique code.

Comment: Numbers that ends in 0 in format_1 will cause the problem?

Comment: yes I figured that out, I am working on a large amount of data and I want an automatic method to solve the problem, thank you

Comment: Do you mean put the zeroes at the front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find duplicates in column `10_char_format` that have a different value in the `format_1` column you can use the formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:A1)/((B2<>$B$1:B1)*(C2=$C$1:C1)),1)),"")
```

[image]

**Explanation:**

The `AGGREGATE` function with the first parameter `15` and the last parameter `1` returns the first smallest value from the array, i.e. acts as a `MIN` function. Unlike the `MIN` function, the second parameter `6` allows errors to be ignored - this is used in this case. The `ROW($A$1:A1)` function returns an array with row numbers, when it is copied down, the array increases (in the sixth row it will already be `ROW($A$1:A5)`). Next, each row number is divided by the result of the expression `((B2<>$B$1:B1)*(C2=$C$1:C1))`, which is an array of bool values (when performing mathematical operations with bool, it is converted to `TRUE`-> `1`, `FALSE`-> `0`), which results in an array with row numbers and errors. Errors are ignored and the smallest row number is returned to the `INDEX` function. For example in the sixth row it looks like this:

```
  INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:A5)/((B6<>$B$1:B5)*(C6=$C$1:C5)),1))
  INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,{1,2,3,4,5}/({TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}*{FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}),1))
  INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,{1,2,3,4,5}/({0,0,1,0,0}),1))
  INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,{Err,Err,3,Err,Err},1))
  INDEX(A:A,3)
```

Comment: this is super helpful but if you please, explain it to me, I'm a little bit lost

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(MOD(B2,10)=0,"Problematic Value???","")
```

[image]

Update:
Will this help?

```
=IF(MOD(B2,10)=0,IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B2)>1,B2,"Single occurrence"),"")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for you replay, this would help a lot but it's just half the solution, I now want to know  if the problematic values have a similar code like :
"1020" its a problematic value... and it similar value that need to be re:encoded is "102";
because there is other values that are indicated as a problematic value but it does not have similar code. thank you

Comment: sorry vanisk, but the answer of @basic was perfect, thank you for your reply